# Setting one input parameter for several models?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters, file-path

I have a bunch of models (about 20) in my custom toolbox. I need to run them one after another and look for some errors which they make in table. I could put all these models into one but it is not allowed for my tasks. 
Nevertheless, I want to ease this work just by making a tool which sets a certain path to my geodatatbase in all models I need to run.

All my models have input parameter of workspace which is GDB base with "Model Parameter" label. After I set this parameter by showing the path to gdb file, I run the model. When process is done I open another model and have to set this path again. 
After the my current geodatabase is scanned for errors, I bring another base, which also has to be checked with that models.
I haven't found yet a tool in System toolbox for automatic setting of input parameters in models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are saying that using submodels is not permitted within your environment.  That seems restrictive, but assuming that it is a mandatory requirement what I would do is:

1. Create a table with one text field and one row and edit it to hold the path to your data.
2. At the start of your models use a [Get Field Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm) tool to read that value into a variable whose name you can then put between percentage signs in the remainder of your model.

> The Get Field Value tool gets the value of the first row of a table
>   for the specified field.

[image]

If you want to use a different path all you need to do is Start Editing that table and type over the old path with a new one.  Nothing will need to change in your models.